# Unable to save data using ajax in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-8

Unable to save data in the database using the ajax function, I have used validation if the record exists it will alert the record already exists, else it will save the data, but here it's only validating the data but not saving the data. I am getting the error $query not defined in the controller. This is my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Haruncpi\LaravelIdGenerator\IdGenerator;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Helpers\Helper;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\User;
use App\Models\patient;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class Helpercontroller extends Controller
{

    public function save(Request $request)
{
   $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
       
        'cnic' => 'required|unique:patients',
    ]);
    
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['success' => false, 'errors' => $validator->errors()->all()]);
    }

    $temppatientId = IdGenerator::generate(['table' => 'patients', 'length' => 5, 'prefix' => '22']);

    $patientid = $temppatientId + 1;

    $query = new patient;
    $query->patientid = $patientid;
    $query->fname =$fname;
    $query->lname = $lname;
    $query->cnic = $cnic;
    $query->contactno = $contactno;
    $query->gender = $gender;
    $query->age = $age;
    $query->dob = $dob;
    $query->city = $city;
    $query->address = $address;
    $query->husbandname = $husbandname;
    $query->fathername = $fathername;
    $query->bloodgroup = $bloodgroup;
    $query->maritalstatus = $maritalstatus;
    

    $query->save();
   

    return response()->json(['success' => true, 'patients' => $query]);
}
```

This is my ajax call

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#save1").on('click', function(e) {

        var cnic = $("#cnic").val();
        
       
        if (cnic == '') {
            alert("Kindly Enter CNIC");
            return false;
        }

        var gender = $("#gender").val();
        if (gender == '') {
            alert("Kindly Enter Gender");
            return false;
        }
       
    



       
        var contactno = $("#contactno").val();
        if (contactno == '') {
            alert("Kindly Enter Contact No");
            return false;
        }
        



        var fname = $("#fname").val();
        if (fname == '') {
            alert("Kindly Enter Name");
            return false;
        }

else{

    $.ajax({
        url: "/save",
        method: "post",
        data: $('#registrationform').serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.success !== false) {
                $("#patientid").val(data.patients.patientid);
               
            } else {
                alert('CNIC already Exists !');
                
            }
        }
  })

}
        
    });
});
```

This is my route

```
Route::post('save', [Helpercontroller::class, 'save'])->name('save');
```

Comment: I don't think that you can use it directly by $fname, you have to add $request->fname; Add $request on all the variables.

Comment: @wiwekchauhan I did, but it's taking null values into DB.

Comment: Your controller is referencing a lot of variables that appear from nowhere. Where are the likes of `$fname` and `$address` etc. coming from? Are these input fields on your form you submit via ajax too? What **exactly** is the **full** error message you're getting and can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73983083/edit) to add more detail?

Comment: @Peppermintology problem resolved as I haven't defined the variable in the controller, anyways thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables appear to be undefined.

```
$query->fname = $request->fname;
```